# Редактирование текста в QListWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Можно ли как нибудь реализовать редактирование в `QListWidget` не открывая дополнительные окна как в данном коде. Т.е. при нажатии на компонент в `QListWidget` сразу можно было в нем же изменить текст. Думаю можно сделать что при нажатии на `item` появлялось на его месте `QLineEdit` и в нем редактирование, но кажется что это не совсем лучшая идея

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class MainWindwos(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 13))
        self.setFixedSize(400, 600)
        self.listwidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.listwidget.resize(400, 600)
        self.listwidget.addItem('привет')
        self.listwidget.itemClicked.connect(self.edit_item)

    def edit_item(self, item):
        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.dialog.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 13))
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.dialog)
        self.edit.resize(200, 30)
        self.push = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.dialog)
        self.push.setText('сохранить')
        self.push.move(0, 50)
        self.push.clicked.connect(lambda: item.setText(self.edit.text()))
        self.push.clicked.connect(lambda: self.dialog.close())
        self.dialog.setFixedSize(200, 200)
        self.dialog.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindwos()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно у элементов списка указывать возможность редактирования через флаг [Qt.ItemIsEditable](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('List Widget Edit')

        self.list_widget = qtw.QListWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.list_widget)

        self.add_item('привет')
        self.add_item('hello')

    def add_item(self, text):
        item = qtw.QListWidgetItem(text)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        self.list_widget.addItem(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Когда у [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#addItem) вызывался `addItem("привет")` это на самом деле скрывало под собой `addItem(QListWidgetItem("привет"))`, а у элементов списка по умолчанию флага редактирования нет.

---

Пример с флагами `item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable)` написан для примера, его можно сократить: `item.setFlags(item.flags() | Qt.ItemIsEditable)`

---

Возможность редактировать элементы настраивается не только у каждого элемента индивидуально, но и через список-виджет через [setEditTriggers](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop). Например этот пример запретит редактирование, хотя у элементов оно разрешено:

```
self.list_widget.setEditTriggers(qtw.QListWidget.NoEditTriggers)
```

Comment: А как нибудь можно назначить изменение не при нажатии на ЛКМ а при нажати ПКМ, Т.е. у меня есть контекстное меню и там будет кнопка редактировать( что соответственно она и должна будет делать), а при нажатии на ЛКМ она выводила названии в `QListWidget`

Comment: 1) Добавить контекстное меню 2) При клике на действие в меню получать текущий элемент 3) Вызывать программно редактирование для элемента: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#editItem . Думаю, сработает, если не будет получаться, создайте отдельный вопрос :)